# Saving image data in SQLite db in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to make a android application that saves image name, langitude, longitude and timestamp into an sqlite database after the image is captured using the android default camera. I managed to take a picture and save it to a specific folder but I am having issues saving the data to tha database. This is my effort this far:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "PHOTO MAP"; 
private Uri fileUri;
File file =new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "PHOTO MAP");

private ImageView imgPreview;
GPSTracker gps;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    try {
        //opening GPSTracker
        GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(this);
        gps = new GPSTracker(CameraActivity.this);
        if(gps.canGetLocation()){
            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        } else {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }   
    } finally{
        //TODO
    }

     imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);

     captureImage();


}

//icture captured or user cancelled
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        galleryAddPic();
        //newPhotograph(imgPreview);
        previewCapturedImage();
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "user cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/*
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    captureImage();
}
*/

//Null pointer exception if not added 
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);


}

//Null pointer exception if not added 
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");

}


//Back pressed returns you to main menu
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent backIntent = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);
    startActivity(backIntent);
    finish();
}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *              HELPER METHODS
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

private void captureImage(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE); 
}

public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    if(!mediaStorageDir.exists()){

        if(!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME,"Failed create" + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + "directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    return mediaFile;
}

private void previewCapturedImage(){
    try{
        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 1;
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),options);
        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        newPhotograph(imgPreview);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//make photo available to android default gallery
private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(file.getPath());
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}

//add photograph to database(with slightly different name though - need fix)
private void newPhotograph(View view){
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    DatabaseHandler dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    Photographs photograph = new Photographs(timeStamp.toString(), String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude()), timeStamp.toString());
    dbHandler.addPhotograph(timeStamp.toString(), String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude()), timeStamp.toString());
}


//method for button over image view to returns as on camera activity
public void cameraActivity(View view){
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(this,
            CameraActivity.class);
    startActivity(cameraIntent);
    finish();
}

//method for button over image view to send as to Map activity
public void mapActivity(View view){
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(this, MapActivity.class);
    startActivity(mapIntent);
    finish();
}
```

}

database handler:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "photographsManager";
private static final String TABLE_PHOTOGRAPHS = "photographs";

private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
//============================================================================= change Photographs.java Double to String???===>changed(Commit??)
private static final String KEY_LAT = "latitude";
private static final String KEY_LON = "longitude";
//==============================================================================
private static final String KEY_TMS = "timeStamp";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_PHOTOGRAPHS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PHOTOGRAPHS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_LAT + " DOUBLE" + KEY_LON + "DOUBLE"  + KEY_TMS + "String" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_PHOTOGRAPHS_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PHOTOGRAPHS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);

}

/*
 * CRUD operations
 */

public void addPhotograph(String name, String Latitude, String Longitude, String timeStamp){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    values.put(KEY_LAT, Longitude);
    values.put(KEY_LON, Longitude);
    values.put(KEY_TMS, timeStamp);

    db.insert(TABLE_PHOTOGRAPHS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public Photographs getPhotograph(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PHOTOGRAPHS, new String[] { KEY_ID }, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    Photographs photograph = new Photographs(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4));
    return photograph;
}

public List<Photographs> getPhotographs(){

    List<Photographs> list = new ArrayList<Photographs>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PHOTOGRAPHS;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Photographs photograph = new Photographs();
            photograph.setID(Integer.valueOf(cursor.getString(0)));
            photograph.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            photograph.setLatitude(cursor.getString(2));
            photograph.setLongitude(cursor.getString(3));
            photograph.setTimeStamp(cursor.getString(4));
            list.add(photograph);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return list;
}
```

}

Photograph model:

```
public class Photographs {

int _id;
String _name;
String _Latitude;
String _Longitude;
String _timeStamp;

//empty constructor
public Photographs(){

}

//constructor
public Photographs(int id, String name, String latitude, String longitude, String timeStamp){
    this._id = id;
    this._name = name;
    this._Latitude = latitude;
    this._Longitude = longitude;
    this._timeStamp = timeStamp;
}

//constructor
public Photographs(String name, String latitude, String longitude, String timeStamp){
    this._name = name;
    this._Latitude = latitude;
    this._Longitude = longitude;
    this._timeStamp = timeStamp;        
}

//ACCESSORS
public int getID(){
    return this._id;
}

public void setID(int id){
    this._id = id;
}

public String getName(){
    return this._name;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this._name = name;
}

public String getLatitude(){
    return this._Latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude){
    this._Latitude = latitude;
}

public String getLongitude(){
    return this._Longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude){
    this._Longitude = longitude;
}

public String getTimeStamp(){
    return this._timeStamp;
}

public void setTimeStamp(String timeStamp){
    this._timeStamp = timeStamp;
}
```

}

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the Null pointer exception occured because of this line of code:

dbHandler.addPhotograph(timeStamp.toString(), String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude()), timeStamp.toString());

from what I read String.valueOf() takes as a parameter an object, and returns the representation as string. valueOf() is implemented like this:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
```

return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}

Since I did not pass an object but rather a premetive type (double) I was geting a null. I changed the way I parsed the double (latitude and longitude) and the problem is fixed. I dont know if the expanation is adequate but now it works.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you break up these long lines of code into shorter ones. It will make it easier to track down issues when they come up. For example, you have four possible reasons for a NPE in this one line of code. If you split it up and assign each piece to a new variable, you can narrow down the cause of the NPE.

Comment: That is what I actually did to narrow down the problem and see what was causing it. Thanks for your input and your time